# C++ - selecting a set of features

Tags: c++, vector, struct, boolean

I'm trying to insert a list of features in a `vector`, and, after that, based on a criterion function's (i.e; formula) result add a feature. The code so far is shown below.

The main parts here I want to ask about are:

1. Do you think it would be a good idea to insert the features in the way made here? That is, as a vector of struct? Or, just add the features immediately? The reason I made a vector of struct is that I want to add integer values to the vector, but, at the same time, to have names for features (i.e; F1, F2, ...etc).
2. For the `criterionFunction()` shown below, I'm trying it to consider for example `features[1]` to have the value `1` if it is selected (i.e; passed to the function) and `0` otherwise. It seems here like something `boolean` is going on? :-) What do you recommend doing here?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::struct Features{ int F1, F2, F3, F4; };

    std::vector<Features> listOfFeatures(4);
    for(std::vector<Features>::iterator i = listOfFeatures.begin(); i != listOfFeatures.end(); i++)
    {
        std::int maxValue = criterionFunction(*listOfFeatures);
    }
}

std::int criterionFunction(std::int *features)
{
    return
        -2*features[1]*features[2]
        +3*features[1]
        +5*features[2]
        -2*features[1]*features[2]*features[3]
        +7*features[3]
        +4*features[4]
        -2*features[1]*features[2]*features[3]*features[4];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not take the time and bother to make the criterion function legible? Easy and reduces bugs. Also, increases the risk that anyone would read your code

Comment: What's an `std::struct`?

Comment: How about using a `enum`? Not sure if that would work for the second part, though.

Comment: Also: std::int? std::struct?! What sorcery is this?

Comment: It looks like someone is trying to translate crappy autogenned C code into 'modern C++' without a clue

Comment: **Do you think it would be a good idea to write almost all your question with a bold font style ?**

Comment: @ereOn you can (suggest) edit(s)

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that compiles and resembles C++, I hope it helps you on your way:

**Edit** Added algorithmics to actually transform all features into a criterion list and get the actual max value of those.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct Features{ int F1, F2, F3, F4; };

int criterionFunction(Features const& features)
{
    return
        -2*features.F1*features.F2
        +3*features.F1
        +5*features.F2
        -2*features.F1*features.F2*features.F3
        +7*features.F3
        +4*features.F4
        -2*features.F1*features.F2*features.F3*features.F4;
}
int main(){

    std::vector<Features> listOfFeatures(4);
    // TODO fill listOfFeatures

    std::vector<int> listOfCriterion;
    std::transform(listOfFeatures.begin(), listOfFeatures.end(), 
            std::back_inserter(listOfCriterion), 
            criterionFunction);

    int maxValue = *std::max_element(
            listOfCriterion.begin(), listOfCriterion.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't touched C++ in awhile, but I'm confused about what you're trying to do.  Based on your questions and sample code, I get the impression you're mixing up what [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/) does.

A vector is collection of objects that can be dynamically sized.  When you call

```
std::vector<Features> listOfFeatures(4);
```

you are making a collection of *4* of your Features structs.  (I.e. room for 16 ints, 4 groups of 4 and I think you just want 4).

I would just stick to a struct if there will always be 4 ints in a Features. If you want to name them and have a variable amount, you'll need to use something like a Map.